# Simulate Timoute and reconnect to OPC server

Tags: load-testing

How can I eviciantly force a timeout in an `OPC XML.da` Connection to force a reconnection and therefore (maybe) a new subscription of real time tags?

To check weather our dev or the manufacturer device is not disposing correctly of old sessions or does not check for reconnections timeout limits.

So I am supposed to try to shut down manufacturer *OPC Server* by reaching 100 subscriptions  using a third party tool to prove our dev team is right and that it is a manufacturer problem - or not . I told them
a free third party tool is *kassel dOPC Explorer.

Is there an elegant way to do this? I mean except opening one connection and then trying to shut down network connection or crash the application?

Our application is using *DANSrvNet4* to connect to the *OPC Server*. Apparently I have no idea how to simulate this.